# Word365 Text Effects Transform option not available

Tags: microsoft-word-365

I have Office 365 installed and I want to use Word's Transform option in Text Effects but it is not an option in the Text Effect drop down menu.

How can I get the Transform option in Word's Text Effects?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I get the Transform option in Word's Text Effects?

As follows:

> The issue that traps most users is that the Transform facilities are
> not available via the Format Shape pane that is accessed by clicking
> on the dialog launcher in the Word Art Styles section of the ribbon:
>
> [image]
>
> Rather, you must expand the Text Effects dropdown in that section of
> the ribbon and then select Transform from the list:
>
> [image]

Source: [Adding text effects (transform option) in Office 365 - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/adding-text-effects-transform-option-in-office-365/eda16698-9734-496f-b16c-52ef321ecbf3?page=2)